# Reverse a number in R

Tags: r, while-loop

I write a code in R to reverse a number. But I got `inf` as output.

```
digit<-512
rev_num<-0
while(digit>0){
  rev_num=rev_num*10 + digit %% 10
 digit=digit / 10
}
print(paste(rev_num))
```

Can anyone tell me the error in this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix to your code (digit here is not an integer, so when you divide it by 10, it goes 51.2, then 5.12 and so on, which is why you got INF as output):

```
digit<-512 
rev_num<-0 
while(digit>0){   
    rev_num=rev_num*10 + digit %% 10 
    digit=as.integer(digit / 10) 
} 
print(paste(rev_num))
```

Another approach to reversing a number:

```
z <- 4321
as.numeric(paste(rev(strsplit(as.character(z),"")[[1]]),collapse=""))
```

Answer (score 5):

You need `digit = digit %/% 10` instead of `/` where `%/%` is to be used for integer division. And you need integer division because using `/` gives residual decimal places and your while loop do not stop until digit reaches the minimum number that can be represented by your machine while your rev_num keep growing by a multiple of 10 in 
each iteration, reaching Inf.

Answer (score 5):

A quick fix to your approach would add `floor` for `digit` when dividing by 10.

```
digit<-512
rev_num<-0

while(digit>0){
  rev_num=rev_num*10 + digit %% 10
  digit= floor(digit / 10)
}

rev_num
#[1] 215
```

---

There is also `stri_reverse` function in `stringi`

```
stringi::stri_reverse(512)
#[1] "215"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you convert the number into a string
Then, You can use **stri_reverse()** function form **stringi**

```
stri_reverse(<String value to reverse>)
```

Then convert the string into Number.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the base R code below, using `toString` + `utf8ToInt` + `intToUtf8`:

```
digit<-512
rev_num <- as.numeric(intToUtf8(rev(utf8ToInt(toString(digit)))))
```